# How to list all countries in select using country_select gem with simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I have added `gem 'country-select'` to my gemfile, and I need to list all countries in a select. I try `<%= f.input :country, as: :select %>` but countries don't appear. There are no info about that in documentation. Please help me with this issue.

Comment: good question, Andrey. There is no full info for this gem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this out

```
<%= f.input :country, as: :country %>
```

Comment: If I may add a small remark: you don't need the `as: :country` argument as attributes containing `country` within their name are automatically mapped to a country select. See the [documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#available-input-types-and-defaults-for-each-column-type)