# Rails Simple Form Country Select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am trying to make an app with Rails and Simple Form with country-select.

I am getting an error that says:

```
wrong number of arguments (4 for 0)
```

I am using the example that i found, for simple form on the country select gem documentation page. I don't understand what's going wrong.

In my model I have:

```
     geocoded_by :address
  after_validation :geocode, if: ->(obj){ @obj.address.present? and @obj.address_changed? }


  def address
    [city, state, participation_country].compact.join(', ')
  end
```

In my form I have:

```
 <%= f.simple_fields_for :scope do |participants_s| %>
      <%= participants_s.simple_fields_for :participant do |par| %>
<%= par.select :participation_country,
                           priority: ["AU", "GB", "NZ", "US"],
                           selected: :participation_country,
                          label: false,
                          prompt: "Select participation country" %>
```

I get the same error when I use

```
<%= par.input :participation_country,
```

In my view I have:

```
<%= @project.scope.participant.address %>
```

Can anyone see what I have done wrong in trying to set this up? The error message indicates the problematic line is:

```
<%= par.select :participation_country,
```

I can't count 4 of anything except suggested country codes, although I deleted one of those to try and I get the same error.

When I try:

```
          <%= par.country_select("participation_country", {:prompt => "Choose Country"})%>
```

I get the same error: wrong number of arguments (4 for 0)

I have also tried removing country-select gem and installing country_select gem instead. The guidance for using country_select gem with simple form has this example:

```
country_select("user", "country", only: ["GB", "FR", "DE"])
```

However the example applications for simple form show this as:

```
  <fieldset>
    <legend>With Only Chosen Countries</legend>
    <%= f.input :country_code, only: ["LV","SG"] %>
    <code>f.input :country_code, only: ["LV","SG"]</code>
```

When I try following the example application as well as the guidance styles, I get errors that don't recognise methods.

Comment: where is the collection from which your select options will appear?

Comment: Hi Emu, what do you mean? I think these are the priority choices and I thought country_select provided a full list

Comment: you can easily do with country gem. Simple form has a integration for it and preferred.

Comment: Hi Rubyrider - I'm trying to use simple form with country select gem. I'm not sure what 'country gem' is but simple form suggests using country select, which I is what im trying to do. I'm not finding this in the slightest bit easy

Comment: sorry my bad, it is country_select gem.

Comment: Well that's whats installed and what im trying to use. I am trying to follow the examples in the country select docs and getting the above error

Comment: @user2860931, you can use `carmen-rails` gem. It's easy to integrate. I never used country_select gem.

Comment: Thnaks emu. I'd like to try and get it working with country select gem since this is the default supported gem

Comment: Never mind, can you please get me a details log from your app server log? I can try to solve with this current gem at least.

Comment: What sort of log output would you like? The current status is as set out under Vamsi's suggestion below

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I finally got this working. I removed the country-select gem (which is recommended for use with simple form) and replaced it with the country_select gem. The wiki for this gem does not use syntax that matches the example application linked on the wiki.

This line ended up working for me:

```
<%= par.input :participant_country, priority: ["AU", "NZ", "GB", "US"], label: false %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change par.select to f.input

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :scope do |participants_s| %>
      <%= participants_s.simple_fields_for :participant do |par| %>
        <%= f.input :participation_country, as: :country, { priority_countries: ["AU", "GB", "NZ", "US"], selected: :participation_country }, { label: false, prompt: "Select participation country" } %>
```

***Reference***:

See Wrapping Rails Form Helpers section in the Readme of [**simple_form**](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#wrapping-rails-form-helpers).

Comment: Hi Vamsi, I tried this but I get this error: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting => (similar to that I set out in more detail in response to Pavan's suggestion below

Comment: It renders the form, but the select options in the drop down menu are: "as", "priority_countries", "label" and "prompt"

Comment: Try the edited code. I guess it should be f.input instead of par.input

Comment: Hi Varnsi, par is the name I gave to f as its nested inside another form

Comment: I tried it, and I get this error: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting =>
...cted: :participation_country }, { label: false, prompt: "Sel...

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
<%= par.input :participation_country, as: :country,
                           priority_countries: ["AU", "GB", "NZ", "US"],
                           label: false,
                           prompt: "Select participation country" %>
```

You don't need to specify `selected` option, form builder will do it for you.

References:

https://github.com/stefanpenner/country_select#usage

[How to list all countries in select using country_select gem with simple_form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302078/how-to-list-all-countries-in-select-using-country-select-gem-with-simple-form)

Comment: Hi Nitish, I tried this but I still get this error: wrong number of arguments (4 for 0)

Comment: That's strange. It is working for me. Did you change `par.select` to `par.input`?

Comment: I did change to par.input

Comment: What exactly is `par`? I can't think of any form builder method which accepts 0 arguments.

Comment: par is the field an i set up. i have added the top of my form to the question

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code

```
<%= par.input :participation_country, as: :country, { priority_countries: ["AU", "GB", "NZ", "US"], selected: :participation_country }, { label: false, prompt: "Select participation country" } %>
```

***Reference:*** See Supplying additional html options part from [**country_select**](https://github.com/stefanpenner/country_select#usage).

Comment: Hi Pavan, I tried this but I get this error: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting =>
 I tried replacing the , with => but it then says its expecting }, I try replacing => with } and it says its expecting there to be nothing after it.